# Facebook Login crash Android

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

I'm trying to integrate Facebook into my Android application. But as soon as I click on the "Log in using Facebook" button, the application closes unexpectedly.

> W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417fcc50)

I'm using the Facebook LoginButton:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
     android:id="@+id/login_button_facebook"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin"/>
```

I also added the following to my build.gradle:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
}
```

I've added a few lines to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Please help!

Comment: no stacktrace available?

Comment: @alessiop86 - I'm Sorry, I'm new to this. Where can I see the stacktrace in Android Studio 1.0.1?

Comment: @alessiop86 I checked. There is nothing except for this: E/dalvikvm﹕ could not disable core file generation for pid 7730: Operation not permitted

Comment: Without more info the only thing I can recommend is to look more thoroughly at the documentation. First make sure you followed every step in the Getting Started docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started, then follow the steps for Android Facebook Login here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2

Comment: You are also using an outdated Facebook SDK, the latest is 3.23.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I only needed to add the following to my manifest file:

```
 <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- install latest facebook sdk.unzip tha facebook sdk an import
- use this code in manifast

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/app_id" />

  <provider
      android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
      android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProviderFacebookAppId"
      android:exported="true" />

  <receiver android:name="YourPackageName.LoginfbBroadcastReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.facebook.platform.AppCallResultBroadcast" />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```